# ServiceStack Service structure for predominantly read-only UI

Tags: servicestack, foreign-key-relationship

I'm getting started with ServiceStack and I've got to say I'm very impressed with all it has under the bonnet and how easy it is to use!

I am developing a predominantly read-only application with it.  There will likely be updates to the database 3 or 4 times a year but the rest of the time the solution will be displaying data on an electronic information board (large touch screen monitor).

The database structure is well normalised with a few foreign keyed tables and with this in mind I think it may be best to separate the read only API from the CRUD API.  The CRUD API can be used to create and modify the relational data with POCO classes matching the database tables.  I would then ensure the read-only API flattens the relational data into a few POCOs spanning a few db tables making the data easier to handle on the read-only UIs.

I'm just looking for ideas and advice really on whether this separation of concerns is wasted effort or if there is a better way of achieving what I need?  Has anyone had similar thoughts / ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having developed a similar read only application (a gazetteer, updated quarterly/yearly) using ServiceStack we went with optimizing the API for reads, making use of the built in caching:

```
    // For cached responses this has to be an object
    public object Any(CachedRequestDto request)
    {

        string cacheKey = request.CacheKey;
        return this.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(
            base.Cache, cacheKey, () =>
                {
                    using (var service = this.ResolveService<RequestService>())
                    {
                        return service.Any(request.TranslateTo<RequestDto>()).TranslateTo<CachedResponseDto>();
                    }
                });
    }
```

Where CacheKey is just:

```
    public string CacheKey
    {
        get
        {
            return UrnId.Create<CachedRequestDto>(string.Format("{0}_{1}", this.Field1, this.Field2));
        }
    }
```

We did start creating a CRUD / POCO service, but for speed went with using bulk import tools such SQL Server DTS/SSIS or console apps which suffices for now, and will revisit this later if required.

Might want to consider something like CQRS.

https://gist.github.com/kellabyte/1964094 (or Google for CQRS Martin Fowler, can only post 2 links).

Also found the following article valuable recently when starting to implement additional search type services: https://mathieu.fenniak.net/stop-designing-fragile-web-apis/

Comment: Thanks Gavin - that's a good point - why create an admin interface at all with such little use intended!